# Memory leak when accessing GCController's gamepad

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I'm adding support for the iOS GameController Framework to a cross-platform input library, and running into some trouble with a memory leak.  Here's a simplified version of the troublesome code:

```
void InputSystem::UpdateControllerState(size_t nControllerIndex)
{
    Controller& c = mController[nControllerIndex];
    GCController* gc = c.mGameController;
    GCExtendedGamepad* gp = [gc extendedGamepad]; // ***

    c.mState[kIOSThumbLX] = gp.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value;
    c.mState[kIOSThumbLY] = gp.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value;
    // ... etc
}
```

The memory leak seems to be caused by the line marked with ***.  I can comment out the lines reading values from the controller and memory is still leaked (under certain circumstances; this could be the key).  I have tried adding [gc release] at the end of the function but that doesn’t seem to have any impact.  This doesn’t really surprise me since I am not retaining the pointer so I should not need to release it.

The interesting thing is that this code works fine in some conditions.  As I was working on the implementation, I set up a basic test that worked just fine.  The problem only showed up when I tried hooking up the existing cross-platform unit tests for this library.  Here is a bit more detail on the two setups:

- (No leak) I set up my InputSystem in applicationDidFinishLaunching,
  along with a displayLink to call a function each frame.  This
  function would call InputSystem code that would call the above
  UpdateControllerState method and then print out any new input (button
  presses, etc) detected.  This setup worked fine; I saw the input from
  the controller that I expected, and memory use stayed nice and flat.
- (Memory leak) In order to test more rigourously, I hooked in the
  cross-platform InputSystem unit tests.  These tests include an
  interactive mode that continuously loops to poll and print out new
  inputs.  This doesn’t give iOS the chance to receive input and update
  the GCController, so I created a new thread in
  applicationDidFinishLaunching to call into the tests.  This worked
  for getting input, but memory use was steadily increasing.  As I
  mentioned above, commenting out parts of the new code helped me
  narrow it down to the highlighted line above.

I don't understand why these two setups behave differently in this way.  Any help understanding this problem would be appreciated.  I don't know at this point if this is a problem with how I am using the GCController class, or something I am not understanding about iOS memory in general.  Thanks!

EDIT: I just tried storing the pointer to the extendedGamepad in my Controller object, so I could read from it directly and remove the line marked with ***.  In this case, however, memory is leaked when I include the lines that read the values from the buttons or thumbsticks.